# User permission on branch level in Git?

Tags: git, version-control, gitlab

I am having trouble understanding how several environments interact with Git if I want to specify permissions for users created in Git.

For example, if I use GitLab, can it handle user permission? If I make changes here will it only affect the web interface or modify access rights on the concrete server that hosts Git?

I've read that Gitolite is a tool to handle authentification...Can I use it in conjunction with GitLab? I'm kinda lost, so thanks in advance.

Comment: gitlab handles authentification too, so yes, gitlab handles access permissions to the repositories.

Comment: What you are looking for is called _protected branches_ in GitLab.

Answer (score 2):

git itself (the protocol, the command line or the physical repository) has no provisions for branch level permissions (or, really, any particularly intelligent persistent permission scheme at all).

GitLab, Gitolite etc. add another layer on top which may or may not be accessible if you do a bare-bones `clone` of the repository; I do not know if they store there permission information in the actual repository at all, or alongside it.

If you want to stay with the default git server model (i.e., over ssh or locally), then you may be able to cobble something together with server side hooks.

Comment: So and can I host Git on my server and then get GitLab or do I simply setup Gitlab and it will bring Git with it?

Comment: GitLab is a standalone program (webserver/webservice) and has nothing much to do with git except that it uses git and allows git to connect to it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitLab

Comment: Okay lets say I set permissions in GitLab will those apply for Git too?